# Refuse page break in BIRT

Tags: datatable, birt, page-break

I'm designing a report which can have one or n elements in dataTable.
If the report has just one element, then I won't have a page break.
If the report has more than one element, then I want after every element a page break.
I got a variable (true or false) which I could asl in a condition if there are more elements.
I'm using eclipse birt version 4.3.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have a footer row or something like that, you can add the following to the onCreate script for that row:

```
if(vars["trueOrFalseVariable"] == true){ this.getStyle().pageBreakAfter = "always"; }
```

And, of course, an `else` if you also want to force no-page-break (but that should probably work automagically if your element is small enough).

Comment: Hi @venite
I tried it on the footer row, but it don't work out. I replaced your variable with my variable from the dataset:
if(row["wholeEmptyEvaluation"] == true){ this.getStyle().pageBreakAfter = "always"; } Unfortunately I don't get an exception.

Comment: Might be because you're using a row, not a variable.